# How to get index of selected option in angular 1

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I see there are similar questions about this topic but none of those are strictly  related to Angular 1.

What I would like to achieve is to get the index of the selected item:

```
.form-group
  label(for="address") Address
  select.form-control(
    id="address"
    name="address"
    ng-model="user.address"
    ng-change="onSelectAddress($index)"
    ng-options="opt as opt.name for opt in addressOptions"
    required
  )
```

Actually I tried to use `$index` and `$event`, both are `undefined`... How can I get the index of selected option through the `onSelectAddress()` function? Is there a way? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this.

> ng-change="onSelectAddress(user.address)"

Then you can find the key by a value in onSelectAddress function, or you can also pass it.

> ng-change="onSelectAddress(user.address, addressOptions)

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand your syntax. However the $index and $event variables are only available for ng-repeat (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat)  and not for ng-options (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions)

So you can use an `<option>` with an ng-repeat